# Can existence of cartesian products be proven without power set axiom?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can it be proven that for any two sets $S$ and $T$, the cartesian product $S \times T$ exists, without using the power set axiom? (But using the other axioms of ZFC is fine)

Comment: That depends on how you code your ordered pairs.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Isn't the power of axiom schema of replacement that it works for pretty much all definitions of ordered pairs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can be proved with replacement and union.

For each $s\in S,$ consider the class function on $T$ that takes $t\mapsto (s,t).$ Then by replacement, there is a set $A_s= \{(s,t): t\in T\}.$ Using replacement again on the class function on $S$ given by $s\mapsto A_s$ gives a set $A=\{A_s:s\in S\},$ and $\cup A=S\times T.$

Comment: If you code the ordered pair $(x,y)$ as $\{\{\mathcal P(x)\},\{\mathcal P(x),\mathcal P(y)\}\}$ then you do need power sets. :-)